# C++ : Semantic issue on a child class with same named method

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

This is a question about designing classes in C++.

My base class have virtual final method with parameters, the name of it is basically "update". In a child class, I wanted to use a higher level way to update the object, so I made a method called "update" too (for convenience), but this one have no parameter. And Clang warns me the method is hiding a base class method. In my point of view, I'm not totally agree with this, because the signature is different, it should just complete the overloading.

Is there a good reason to not do that ?

Comment: What is your understanding of what a "final method" is?

Comment: oh it's "virtual _t update(params ...) final;", I don't want this method to be overloaded by a child class.

Comment: Well, so what exactly are you unsure about, regarding your compiler's diagnostic?

Comment: nothing, I'm pretty sure about what i'm doing, but I like to stick to clang/gcc recommendation

Comment: Well, yes, sometimes the compiler's diagnostics are not telling you something that you don't already know. In some exceptional case I just looked up how to shut it up, in a particular, specific instance, when I know what I'm doing and I don't need the compiler's advice.

Comment: My idea is to make a virtual method in the base class open for overloading which do nothing, but I find it non-sense, because this method will appear to all other child classes, and I don't want that.

Comment: The other solution is to name the child method differently, but in this particular case, it's not elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is telling you that the function in the derived class makes it more difficult to call the original base class function on an object of the derived type:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void update(int param) final;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void update();
};

void f(Derived& obj) {
    obj.update(2); // Error!
    // Name lookup for update finds only Derived::update,
    // which takes no arguments
}
```

To "unhide" the base class function, so that the derived class acts as though it has both overloads, use a `using` directive:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void update();
    using Base::update;
};
```